# C# Monitor and update

Tags: c#, .net

In my program (basic task manager) I monitor a list of processes, and allow to make changes to process (e.g. kill a process or raise its priority).

To implement it I design it as follows: one thread is the worker thread that does all the work, one thread is updating the status in the GUI. There is a processes list, and I use lock to make it thread-safe. The thing is I'm scanning all the processes on a regular interval (say 1 second) and in the meanwhile I cannot make changes to the list, as another thread is working on it. Therefore my program lag sometimes to display the operation

Is this a good design? What can I do to improve it? I think to lower the interval value.

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far? That will make it far easier to offer advice.

Comment: You may not need all those threads, locking and synchronization. I would probably use a GUI timer to execute the periodic task. Perhaps you have the time fire every 25 msec and only process 1 item in the list, the trick being finding the next item since the list/order may have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having a shared list, consider having a list that your worker thread maintains which is the master list.  Once it has done its scan it then passes a *copy* of the master list to the GUI thread.  The GUI thread is then able to update the GUI with the new information contained in the copy whilst the worker thread can be performing another scan.

This removes the need for a lock, because the worker thread is only ever writing to one list and then taking creating a copy (in the same thread).

One problem with this approach is what happens if the background worker is able to gather a new process list faster than the GUI can update.  You need to be able to deal with receiving a new process list while it is still processing the previous update.